# Concrete5 Migrate Users with Groups and Attributes

Tags: concrete5

I need to migrate all of my users from one web server to another with all their permissions intact. I'm not sure if this can be done via copying database tables and dropping them in to the other server. Or if there is a tool to do this?

The `Export to CSV` button pulls off my entire user list but without their groups and without any attributes so doesn't serve the purpose I need.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a couple months since you asked so you've probably already figured this out but, you should be able to export the entire DB of your site and import it on the new webserver if you are migrating the whole site. If you just need the users and groups then you'll likely want the `Groups, UserAttributeKeys, UserAttributeValues, UserGroups,  Users, UserSignupNotifications, UserSignups` tables. I haven't had any issues with password not working when pulling the entire database, but if you do you may want to look at the row in the the Config table `where configItem='security.token.encryption'` and make sure those match between the two sites

You can export this from the original side with `mysqldump -u <username> -p <database_name> Groups UserGroups Users UserSignupNotifications UserSignups > user_data.sql`

Then on the receiving end you can do something like mysql -u  -p  < user_data.sql` but note **this will overwrite the data on the receiving end**

There are more tables involved if you need to copy over attributes associated with a user. If you do a `SHOW TABLES LIKE "User%"; SHOW TABLES LIKE "Group%"; SHOW TABLES LIKE "Permission%";` that should cover the majority of them. You could add those to the listing of tables to export and pull those over as well.